# What is the main difference between chmod and chown?

Tags: command-line, permissions, users, chmod, chown

In some examples, I saw that some used `chown` instead of `chmod`. I do not know where to use `chmod` and `chown`. Please explain to me the difference between them, when and why I should use either.

Comment: Nobody's made it explicit yet: one **ch**anges the **mod**e and the other **ch**anges the **own**er. Also, read the **man**ual.

Comment: And while `chown` can also **ch**ange the **gr**ou**p**, there is `chgrp` dedicated specifically to this task.

Comment: What's the main difference between a banana and a chair? Don't sit on the banana.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Let's create a file

```
touch rainbow
```

Let's have a look at the file's metadata

```
$ ls -l rainbow
-rw-rw-r-- 1 zanna zanna 0 May 24 10:09 rainbow
```

The first part of the information is the file type (`-` at the beginning means it's a regular file) and the permission bits

[image]

After that we see the owner (zanna) and the group (zanna). We can use the `chown` command to change those:

```
$ sudo chown pixie rainbow
$ ls -l rainbow
-rw-rw-r-- 1 pixie zanna 0 May 24 10:09 rainbow
```

And we use `chmod` to change the permission bits

```
$ sudo chmod 333 rainbow
$ ls -l rainbow
--wx-wx-wx 1 pixie zanna 0 May 24 10:09 rainbow
```

Since the permission bits are set separately for owner, group and others, you can control file permissions for different users by combining `chown` and `chmod`. See [this short guide](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_lts0090.php) for a crash course on permissions in Linux.

Comment: +1 for image.. No octal def though? Or `chmod a+w` example? Which is time consuming to do but gets more votes I think :D

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix haha thanks... I deliberately chose a particularly useless permissions setting. If I really start explaining when and why to use every possible permutation of `chmod` and `chown` (which is too broad a question by far) my answer will go on forever. Trying to keep it simple

Comment: confused what's a difference between ownership and permissions? is the difference that only owner can update permission?

Comment: @MuhammadUmer ownership is who owns the file, permissions are what owners and non owners can do with it

Comment: It seems like the link to the article is broken, here is the fixed one: [this short guide](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_lts0090.php)

Answer (score 117):

In simple term
`chown` is used to change the ownership of a file while `chmod` is for changing the file mode bits.

- `chown` defines who owns the file.
- `chmod` defines  who can do what.

---

When you make someone the owner of a file, (s)he can do almost wherever (s)he want to that file, for example (s)he can use `chmod` to changes its mods (say permissions) to define who can do what.

```
$ ls -l file
-rwxrwxr-x  2  ravexina admins   26 May  9 12:49 file
```

At the above line we can see that `ravexina` is the owner of the file and `admins` is the group. I can use: `sudo chown dave:sudo file` to change the owner of the file to `dave` and the group to `sudo`; Now the file belongs to "dave" and everyone in "sudo" group.

However with `chmod` we define who can do what? who has the right to read a file, write to a file or execute it. e.g:

```
chmod 777 file
```

gives the rights of read, write and execute to everyone including owner, group and everyones else.

From [turnoff.us](http://turnoff.us):
[image]

Comment: The owner cannot do whatever they want to the file - deleting or moving requires write permissions on the containing directory.

Comment: @muru that's true ;) I meant read/write/exec, there's also `chattr` which can effects the file I guess.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I haven't asked you to pretend anything. What you're missing is that most people don't think of deleting or renaming a file as being operations on the directory, but as operations on the file. That's why we have questions like these: https://superuser.com/q/373115/334516, https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/48579/70524, https://askubuntu.com/q/240424/158442 Obviously you know these are operations on the directory (congratulations!), but there's a common misconception about that, so I noted that renaming or deleting involve permissions on the directory, not the file. ...

Comment: I too upvoted just for the comic :-) However, you may want to expand on `chmod`. The reason it's not called `chperm` (other than early UNIX bods not liking long command names) is that it's for other things as well (setuid, setgid, stick bits, etc). Hence the name "change mode".

Comment: @paxdiablo Thanks :-) The reason I didn't explain the details in my answer is that I was trying to show just enough difference to get the comic point. I did an update ;)

Comment: why not add an additional permission which grants users the permission to grant permissions? In which case we have no more need for chown

Answer (score 22):

When considering the permissions of a file (or directory, or whatever), there are two factors:

- *who* owns the file - the user and group, and
- *what* they can do with it - read, write, execute or a combination thereof.

`chown` deals with the *who*. `chmod` deals with the *what*. You can't use one instead of the other.

Simple Unix permissions classify users trying to access a file into three types:

1. the owner of the file
2. users who are members of the group owning the file
3. everybody else

`chown` is used to change the first two. `chmod` is used to change the rights granted to these types.

Answer (score 10):

A few points/tips to add to the previous excellent answers:

- You must have execute permission on a directory (and all those above it) to access it
- Use the -R option to apply the changes recursively to everything including and below the target, e.g. `chown -R www-data files/`
- You can change user and group at the same time by using the syntax `chown user:group myfile`
- Often it's easier/better to use the '+' and '-' options rather than setting absolute permissions, especially when dealing with a combination of files and directories. For example if you want to give group write permissions to a directory and everything below it, `chmod -R 775 files/` would make 'files/' and everything in and below it executable and readable to all, which might not be the desired outcome for every file. Using `chmod -R g+w files/` will just add the group write permission without touching anything else.

Answer (score 9):

Very good answers already, but I would like to make a contribution where the permissions is very easy to understand

`chmod u=r+w,o=r-w,g=-r-w test.php`

```
u = user
o = other
g = group
```

This way you can easily append permissions to a file. In the example above

```
user = read + write
other = read but not write
group = not read not write
```

And don't forget the `-R` if you want to change permissions recursively.

Answer (score 5):

`chown` Will change **who** owns the file and what group it belongs, while `chmod` changes **how** the owners and groups can access the file (or if they can access it at all).