# Is there documentation for chown that is easier to understand?

Tags: chown, manpage

I am relatively knew to Ubuntu and I want to learn about the `chown` command, so I tried to read the `man chown` but I find it very difficult to understand. Is there a document for this that is simpler and easier to understand?

Comment: You might be interested in reading https://askubuntu.com/q/918379/295286 for basics.

Comment: Actually I'd like to encourage you to try to understand the man page. It needs some getting used to, but the format is uniform. A few hints: rectangular brackets in the synopsis indicate optional items. These can be nested. E.g. `[OWNER][:[GROUP]]` means that you can omit `owner` or `:[group]` or both or none; the brackets in `:[group]` indicate that you can omit the actual group; the description explains what happens then (" If  a colon  but  no group name follows the user name, [...] the group of the files is changed to that user's login group."

Comment: But then I didn't know about the tldr project Nykakin mentions in his answer. Awesome, even for more experienced users, because it just covers 90% of your daily use cases. Some man pages (e.g. for `find`) include examples but many which would profit from some don't, at least on my cygwin here (e.g. `tar`).

Comment: Online versions can be found which sometimes are tweaked a bit e.g. https://ss64.com/bash/chown.html . https://ss64.com/bash/chmod.html is is especially helpful for new users as it has a nice little tick box calculator for using the numeric options.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Actually there is such documentation. Open a command line terminal - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>  and enter:

```
info chown
```

you will find this document uses less technical terms and phrasing, and explains the command in a more "conversational" manner. It is therefore easier to read and understand for beginner users.

After reading the `info` page I recommend familiarizing yourself with the `man` page for `chown`, because the `man` pages tend to be more succinct and complete.

Comment: `info chown` takes you to the documentation of the libc function. `info coreutils chown` takes you to the command's documentation. Though maybe it's different because I'm running Arch.

Comment: @JoL It's not the case for Ubuntu 18.04 - the answer is correct.

Answer (score 29):

I suggest installing [tldr](https://github.com/tldr-pages/tldr) project:

```
$ tldr chown
# chown                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       

  Change user and group ownership of files and folders.                                                                                                                                                                                       

- Change the owner user of a file/folder:                                                                                                                                                                                                     

  chown user path/to/file                                                                                                                                                                                                                     

- Change the owner user and group of a file/folder:                                                                                                                                                                                           

  chown user:group path/to/file                                                                                                                                                                                                               

- Recursively change the owner of a folder and its contents:                                                                                                                                                                                  

  chown -R user path/to/folder                                                                                                                                                                                                                

- Change the owner of a symbolic link:                                                                                                                                                                                                        

  chown -h user path/to/symlink                                                                                                                                                                                                               

- Change the owner of a file/folder to match a reference file:                                                                                                                                                                                

  chown --reference=path/to/reference_file path/to/file
```

Comment: Wanted to post same answer; I got this from dev.to srticle; also can be installed on Mac (`brew install tldr`).

Answer (score 7):

Not supposed to post link only answers (for which I apologise) but I think [this](https://www.howtoforge.com/linux-chown-command/)
link might be what you are looking for as it explains things in simple detail with examples.

Comment: Link-only answers are acceptable if the entire point of the question is to find documentation ("the linked resource *contains* the answer" vs. "this linked resource *is* the answer"). We don't require or want those to be cited in-line. ;-]

Comment: @DavidFoerster: Still, there's a reasonable chance that this answer will be useless in a few months or years.

Answer (score 1):

I love the linux today tutorials. Just google linux today and command you are looking for. Most common commands have articles.

https://www.howtoforge.com/linux-chown-command/